# Zenpy incremental export gives tickets before start_date

Tags: python-3.x, zendesk, zendesk-api

I am trying to use zenpy to get information on tickets created or modified in the last week. This is the code I am using:

```
stream_status = False #Exit condition
while(stream_status==False):
    print(start_date)
    all_tickets = zendesk.tickets.incremental(start_time=start_date, include=['users','organizations'])
    print(len(all_tickets))
    print(all_tickets.end_time)
    for ticket in all_tickets:
            #grab ticket fields and store them in a Dataframe            
            df.loc[len(df)] = [ticket_id,created_at,requester,organization,product,subject,assignee,status,priority,opened_at,opened_by,solved_at,solved_by,closed_at,closed_by]
            count +=1
            print(count,ticket_id)
    start_date = all_tickets.end_time
    stream_status = all_tickets.end_of_stream
    print(start_date,stream_status)
today = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")
df.to_excel('Ticket_report{0}.xlsx'.format(today))
```

Now there are several issues here. The date is calculated correctly and it's indeed 7 days ago. But the tickets I am getting are going back to at least April and they were definitely not been modified since. I stopped it at this point cause we have thousands of tickets.
Also, the incremental method returns a max of 1000 ticket objects, but even after 1000 the loop doesn't seem to restart (print statement at the end doesn't trigger). I am not sure I am using the stream_status flag correctly. Any advice is more than welcome. Thank you!

Zenpy documentation on incremental can be found here: http://docs.facetoe.com.au/zenpy.html#incremental-exports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an API issue after all.

For anyone facing similar issues, turns out that the start date is compared against the generated_timestamp instead of the updated_at or created_at fields. Updated_at holds the last action that generated a ticket event(e.g. change) but generated_timestamp is updated every time the ticket is affected even from the system. That leads to grabbing tickets updated or created before the input date. A solution for that is to filter out the results after the call:

```
all_tickets = zendesk_client.incremental(start_time=start_date)
accurate_tickets = [ticket for ticket in all tickets if  parser.parse(ticket.updated_at) > start_date]
```

Not very sure why they designed the API like this, seems a bit wrong, but that's how it works unfortunately.

Source: https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/ticketing/managing-tickets/using-the-incremental-export-api/#excluding-system-updated-tickets-time-based-exports